# Find a line of text with a pattern using Windows command line or Python

Tags: python, windows, parsing, powershell, cmd

I need to run a command line tool that verifies a file and displays a bunch of information about it. I can export this information to a txt file but it includes a lot of extra data. I just need one line for the file:

"The signature is timestamped: Thu May 24 17:13:16 2012"

The time could be different, but I just need to extract this data and put it into a file. Is there a good way to do this from the command line itself or maybe python? I plan on using Python to locate and download the file to be verified, then run the command line tool to verify it so it can get the data then send that data in an email.

This is on a windows PC.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You mean like `grep 'The signature is timestamped:' originalfile > exportfile`?

Comment: If one of the answers is good enough you should select it as the one you accepted(putting a green check mark next to it), by clicking on the white check mark under the upvote/downvote buttons for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use Python to do this. If you're using a Unix environment, you can use `fgrep` right from the command-line and redirect the output to another file.

```
fgrep "The signature is timestamped: " input.txt > output.txt
```

On Windows you can use:

```
find "The signature is timestamped: " < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I am using windows for this, the ideal way would be to just export the one line directly from the command line. But right now I can export the whole thing to a text file, then just find some way to extract that one line from it and make a file if I have to.

Comment: @BrianLeeJones I added a Windows command-line solution. In the future, please specify which platform you are using.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm just starting into coding and figured command line was unique to windows. This line of code is perfect and easily does what I need, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You mention the command line utility "displays" some information, so it may well be printing to `stdout`, so one way is to run the utility within Python, and capture the output.

```
import subprocess
# Try with some basic commands here maybe...
file_info = subprocess.check_output(['your_command_name', 'input_file'])
for line in file_info.splitlines():
    # print line here to see what you get
    if file_info.startswith('The signature is timestamped: '):
        print line # do something here
```

This should fit in nicely with the "use python to download and locate" - so that can use urllib.urlretrieve to download (possibly with a temporary name), then run the command line util on the temp file to get the details, then the smtplib to send emails...

Answer (score 1):

In python you can do something like this:

```
timestamp = ''
with open('./filename', 'r') as f:
  timestamp = [line for line in f.readlines() if 'The signature is timestamped: ' in line]
```

I haven't tested this but I think it'd work. Not sure if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about the exact syntax of this exported file you have, but python's `readlines()` function might be helpful for this.

```
h=open(pathname,'r') #opens the file for reading
for line in h.readlines():
    print line#this will print out the contents of each line of the text file
```

If the text file has the same format every time, the rest is easy; if it is not, you could do something like

```
for line in h.readlines():
    if line.split()[3] == 'timestamped':
         print line
         output_string=line
```

as for writing to a file, you'll want to open the file for writing, `h=open(name, "w")`, then use `h.write(output_string)` to write it to a text file

Comment: Not exactly ideal for command line in this format, but the functions used will still work